# python manage.py test: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm fairly new at testing and while trying to run test for my django project using `python manage.py test` i end up getting `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user`.

I have the User model within the accounts app and the accounts app has been added to installed app within my settings.py

I've run makemgirations and migrate for all project apps, i've also gone into the project shell and try creating a user from User model in the accounts app and all of these works well, but when i run my test i get an error.

below is the test i'm trying to run which generates the error

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class UserTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        USER = get_user_model()
        USER.objects.create(
            email="johndoe@example.com", first_name="John", last_name="Doe"
        )
        USER.objects.create(
            email="janedoe@example.com", first_name="Jane", last_name="Doe"
        )

    def test_user_full_name(self):
        """ A user's fullname correctly identified """
        jane = USER.objects.get(email="janedoe@example.com")
        john = USER.objects.get(email="johndoe@example.com")

        self.assertEqual(jane.get_full_name(), "Jane Doe")
        self.assertEqual(john.get_full_name(), "John Doe")
```

and below is the code i ran within project shell that works

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
USER = get_user_model()
USER.objects.create(
     email="johndoe@example.com", first_name="John", last_name="Doe"
)
USER.objects.create(
     email="janedoe@example.com", first_name="Jane", last_name="Doe"
)

USER.objects.all()

# returns both object that has been added
```

and below is my database settings

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'TEST': {
            'test_NAME': 'test_db',
        }
    }
}
```

**Please how can this be resolved**

Below is the full stack trace

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 381, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line
629, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line
554, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 174, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\creation.py", line 72, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 148, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 341, in sync_apps
    self.stdout.write("    Running deferred SQL...\n")
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 34, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 341, in check_constraints
    column_name, referenced_column_name,
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\i-am-prinx\.virtualenvs\ProjectName-2t3W9LfY\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 381, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user
```

**Tools and versions**
django v 2.2
python v 3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main cause of this issue was because an app within the project had a model with a foreignkey field to the `User` model and this said app was not having `migrations` folder and the models in the app (including those having foreignkey reference to the `User` model ) was not migrated (note that this said app is in installed app).
I resolved this issue by following these steps

** steps and explanation of what i noticed**

- I deleted the `db.sqlite3` file on my project root

  - I deleted the migrations directory on all apps ( not all apps had migrations folder though i ran `python manage.py makemigrations`, reason for this i really don't know ). The only app that was having migrations folder was the `accounts` app.
  - I then explicitly ran `makemigrations` for all apps ( test worked even without explicitly running migrate command, so far `makemigrations` has been run) and then i ran `python manage.py migrate` command

** for the above code **

```py
class UserTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        USER = get_user_model()  # <---  doing this here generates error when using USER.get() in the test_... methods
        USER.objects.create(
            email="johndoe@example.com", first_name="John", last_name="Doe"
        )
        USER.objects.create(
            email="janedoe@example.com", first_name="Jane", last_name="Doe"
        )

    def test_user_full_name(self):
        """ A user's fullname correctly identified """
        jane = USER.objects.get(email="janedoe@example.com")
        john = USER.objects.get(email="johndoe@example.com")

        self.assertEqual(jane.get_full_name(), "Jane Doe")
        self.assertEqual(john.get_full_name(), "John Doe")
```

The above code will fail and the correct code should be

```py
USER = get_user_model() 
class UserTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        USER.objects.create(
            email="johndoe@example.com", first_name="John", last_name="Doe"
        )
        USER.objects.create(
            email="janedoe@example.com", first_name="Jane", last_name="Doe"
        )

    def test_user_full_name(self):
        """ A user's fullname correctly identified """
        jane = USER.objects.get(email="janedoe@example.com")
        john = USER.objects.get(email="johndoe@example.com")

        self.assertEqual(jane.get_full_name(), "Jane Doe")
        self.assertEqual(john.get_full_name(), "John Doe")
```

I hope this is able to help someone

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me;

Delete all the migration files and then run

```
python .\manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

It should work.

Comment: It worked for me too. And the 'syncdb' means "Allows creating tables for apps without migrations. While this isn’t recommended, the migrations framework is sometimes too slow on large projects with hundreds of models." - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-run-syncdb

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your database settings like so (this depends on which django version you are using):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i've just done that and i still get same error and i'm working with django 2.2